# How do I start creating an app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I am completely new to app dev and coding. I need bit of help understanding this all. I am using visual studio and Xamarin, I cant see anywhere that has concise instructions on how to create single page app that has multiple pages - and will this even work for the app I am wanting to develop as it is an app where users would login with their own profiles etc ... please help - I have been doing this for 6 weeks and I have nothing yet:(

The App I want to do must be multi platform.

Comment: Talk us through your progress in the last 6 weeks. What have you tried? What tutorials have you followed? What has worked? What hasn't worked?

Comment: Hi, Ok so I have tried creating grids so that each page would be a grid? but I also have a problem with understanding how to make this work on the xaml and C# pages. I have basically gotten an out line of what I want the landing screen to look like but no further... to be honest I also haven't even managed to add an image :(

Comment: I have also tried stacks etc but I have getting errors so basically I am back to starting all over again with nothing - so just need some guidance and maybe step by step instructions - I do know I wont actually find those -I am just frustrated

Comment: I'd suggest adding those details to your question (rather than as comments).

Comment: [Xamarin Book PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

to create an app you can search over some youtube lectures on android , furthermore you can use panels in your application to keep it a one page application.

Answer (score 1):

Programming isn't something you can start with a serious project, unless you're ready to commit months to learn and build.

You've been at it for 6 weeks; if you haven't progressed one bit, maybe it's time to admit you're not doing your learning the right way.

If you're dead set in continuing like that, the best I can tell you is to look at [Xamarin.Forms samples](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/all/), study them, and take pieces here and there. Knowing which pieces to take will need its own learning.

There is really nothing more for us to do to help you. Learning programming by itself takes time, more than 6 weeks, while you want to jump in a serious project already.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, welcome to the world of programming! 
You might have had a kind of frustrating start, because you set yourself a goal like "i want to create an app". Don't get me wrong, there is nothing wrong about creating an app, but if you haven't written a single line of code before, I would suggest starting with the very basics of c#.

These would teach you the basic principles about the language, give you an understanding of how classes and methods work and how all that stuff works "under the hood" of the app you want to create.

You can take a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/index.htm which does a great job on that. Of course you could also get a book about starting programming with C#.

I know that in the beginning, it isn't as "cool" as having an app appearing on screen, but with that foundation, you will find yourself understanding most of the app design and programming tutorials way easier and way faster and eventually you will end up getting great results with an app much faster, as soon as you have understood the basics.

In the beginning, you will start with basic console applications (just text in- and output), as soon as you are through that, you can start with a small app. Alternatively, you might try Windows WPF applications, because they are quite fast to write and compile (since you don't have to bother with android and ios, though tankfully Xamarin takes a lot of that burden from you) and also give you a good understanding and practise in how xaml and xaml.cs files go together.

However, no matter what you end up doing: Keep trying. Programming isn't just about learning the syntax of a language, in order to become a good programmer, you need experience and that is what you will get over time.

I wish you good luck